# Unable to fix Ubuntu 16.04 “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

In an attempt to set up an external monitor, I have screwed up my Ubuntu 16.04 Dell laptop. Seems like I messed up the graphic drivers and now I am stuck at the “The system is running in low-graphics mode” screen with no option to proceed after booting.

I can only run commands from a terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1.

Output of lspci command says `VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices. Inc [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730] (rev ff)`

Here is what I have tried so far:

- I tried to fix the issue by following [this step-by-step guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error/141607#141607). However, no luck. Especially, `sudo apt-get install fglrx` yield no such package.
- I also followed the [official guidelines by AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635). No luck here as well. No noticeable errors as such. But, the error message "system is running in low-graphics mode” still persists after reboot.
- As a last resort, I tried to upgrade to 18.04 LTS through a bootable flash USB. To my bad luck, there is no option to upgrade, and it shows only install alongside or erase/reinstall.

I have spent almost 8 hours trying to debug now, and all my trials are getting useless and redundant. Any help to guide me in the right direction would be much appreciated. What am I missing basically?

Comment: I recall having problems with ATI card and I had to cleanly install Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Oh :( Clean install as in you lost all the files and folders you had in 16.04?

Comment: I did the clean install but I didn't reformat /home. I used advanced Ubuntu install. Perhaps you should post some logs here? Try the log of the X Server at least ...

Comment: What should be the command of X server log?

Comment: Have you tried `startx /etc/X11/Xsession failsafe` yet?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to **rebuild kernel with AMD graphics support activated**.

Just fetch kernel source from kernel.org, then extract it, open config interface:

```
curl https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.0.1.tar.xz > ~/linux-5.0.1.tar.xz
tar -Jxvf linux-5.0.1.tar.xz
cd linux-5.0.1
make defconfig
make menuconfig
```

In menuconfig, locate to "Device Drivers"-->"Graphics Support", select "AMD GPU", press "Y".

["Device Drivers" menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uehm.png)

Save the configuration, then build:

```
make
sudo make modules_install
sudo make install
```

After reboot, your Ubuntu should recognize your AMD GPU.

Comment: Perhaps compiling the newest kernel isn't the way for an average user. Probably he'd be better off with a LTS kernel version.